# Is there a disadvantage in too much granularity in structuring projects?

Tags: .net, oop, solid-principles

I have many classes in my BLL. Supposed I have ItemBLL, ItemType BLL, EmployeeBLL etc., is there any disadvantage in placing them in a separate project each? Some of them are logically groupable but is there any problem in placing each class in a separate project (lets say maintaining them isn't a problem).

How about benefits of grouping them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complexity is the biggest problem.  The more assemblies you have, the more you have to keep track of.  If an application needs something from one, there is a good possibility that it will need to have a reference to the others anyway if they are inner connected.

This isn't to say that having more assemblies is bad.  There can be advantages to having them separate, such as which ones are loaded into memory when (they are loaded on demand when the application needs them).

There is no hard and fast rule to which one is better, it depends on the situation.  Personally, unless you have a reason to have them separate, I would combine them.  It makes deployment and administration easier in the long run.  Also keeping classes in the same assembly (at least in C# with the [internal modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx)), gives you the ability to give them the ability to access functions internal to the assembly while blocking reference classes external to it.